# There is no html code after php code, not appear and the html page ends

Tags: php, html

This code is into an HTML site and specifically in this page http://newpage.photoclub-tey.com.cy/NewMember.php is the FB button at the bottom of the page but after the PHP code the HTML code (footer etc. ) does not appear. I close all the tags I think but nothing happend.

```
<div class="container">

            <form class="row form">
                <h2>Μπορείτε επίσης να εγγραφείται με Gmail ή με Facebook.</h2>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-4 form-group">

                    <?php echo $output; ?>

                </div> <!-- /.form-group -->
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-4 form-group">

                    <label class="sr-only">Name</label>




                <?php
//initialize facebook sdk
require 'facebooklogin/Facebook/autoload.php';
session_start();
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
 'app_id' => '',
 'app_secret' => '',
 'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
]);

unset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
unset($accesstoken);


...
$facebook->getAccessToken();
unset($_SESSION['_SESSION']);
unset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
unset($_SESSION);
$accessToken->revokeToken();
session_destroy();

?>
</div>
</form>
<hr>
```

Comment: `<?php` comes twice

Comment: @Banzay i fix it and the problem is still here

Comment: Is this your full html code. Their is no mention of footer in this code and in this page
 http://newpage.photoclub-tey.com.cy/NewMember.php. If present kindly provide some class or id to the footer, So that I can inspect it.